# Hosting a specific site path on a seperate server

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, apache2.4

**Minimal example of problem to solve**:

I have examplesite.com currently hosted on an ec2 instance with apache2.4

The path /support on examplesite.com is a wordpress site for non development teams to manage and interact with customers. For security reasons I want to host /support on a separate server to the rest of the app as a part of many changes which need to be made.

Login must persist between the main site and /support as users must be logged in to access /support, else they'll be redirected back to examplesite.com/login. This means cookies must be shared, sessions are stored in a database along with session lifetime, last modified date, and other data.

**What I've done so far**:

- Spun up and set up an ec2 instance for the support site with all needed ssl certificates as well as an elastic ip and domain. Codebase is the same for both support and the main site.
- Both the main and new instance share a domain, one has the subdomain 'app' while the other has the subdomain 'support'
- Attempted to set up forward and reverse proxies (from a testing environment not prod) to use the new ec2 instance for /support. However I kept getting `pass request body failed to {ip}`. I couldn't find a solution, but I could possibly reattempt, or have a 3rd server which acts as a proxy to both the main site and /support hosted section (although I'd prefer to avoid an extra server to maintain).
- Set up redirects in htaccess so all non /support paths on the support ec2 instance are redirected back and all /support paths on the main app are redirected to the support ec2 instance. However this doesn't solve the persisting login issue. Although it can be used to stop users from accessing non /support paths when on the support ec2 instance.

Would aws loadbalancing be a potential solution? What other solutions may be available to me? Does anyone know any solutions to my deadends from previous attempts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in the end by setting up an application load balancer on aws. I had 2 load balancing target groups, one contained just the main site, the other contained just the support server. After creating these and setting up targets / ssl certificates and the like I selected the created load balancer I made, went to listeners, then edited them with the provided aws tools to forward any path matching /support* to the support server, and the rest goes by default to the webapp. I did this for both port 80 and 443 as you'd expect. All that was left then was to swap over the domain from the main app server to the load balancer ip.